# Typo on the "header" for the site

Tags: bug, status-completed

Towards the top of the page on the beta site it looks like a typo:

> got a question about the site **iteself**?
>   meta.apple is the place to talk about
>   things like what questions are
>   appropriate, what tags we should use,
>   etc

Should read:

> got a question about the site **itself**?
>   meta.apple is the place to talk about
>   things like what questions are
>   appropriate, what tags we should use,
>   etc

Totally not a biggie but thought I'd mention it.  (Give me a schweet shirt please!)

Comment: Nice catch!` ` ` `

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, nice catch.